# Make a frame around text and include a header

Tags: mdframed

I'd like to make a frame (probably using mdframed) as in the example picture I included. I looked around on this website and tried to google the think, but I don't even know how to desrcibe this in words (when I type "header" or "text inside frame" I get very different results. Sorry, I'm not a native speaker).

The example is taken from a slide of a statistics course I attended a while ago. Unfortunately, I don't have the LaTeX-file, only the finished PDF document. Would be great if anyone could give me a hint how to do this in LaTeX. Thanks!

[image: Example Frame]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an starting point with `tcolorbox`. From there you can configure whatever you want, font, colors, corners, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,fonttitle=\ttfamily,fontupper=\ttfamily,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{R code}
boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE)
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Next one looks more similar to what's wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
    fonttitle=\ttfamily,
    fontupper=\ttfamily,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={colframe=white},
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm}, 
    title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{R code}
boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE)
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With only `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{mybox}[1][]{%
 \noindent
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[minimum width=\linewidth-0.4pt,draw,text width=\linewidth-12pt,,font=\ttfamily] (a){\BODY};
   \node[fill=white,yshift=0.5ex,font=\ttfamily] at (a.north) {#1};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
```

[image]